# ListView layout weight

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I have two LinearLayouts in my main activity. One of them is used to hold Buttons and the other one is used to hold ListViews. I add them dynamically by clicking the button at the bottom of the screen.

I also want to set their layout weight (`3f` for 1st and 2nd button and list and `1f` for third one)

So, this is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="majewski.ninja.myphonelibrary.ListActivity"
    android:background="#000000">


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/fragmentsHolder">
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/fragmentsHolder"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/listsHolder"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add new fragment"
        android:id="@+id/addFragmentButton"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Thats how I add buttons and ListViews:

```
private void addButtonAndList(String columnName) {
    // returns a button with setted name and layout params
    Button button = getButton(columnName);
    // returns a list with setted name and layout params
    ListView list = getNewListView(columnName);
    // simply adds views to two of my layouts
    addToLayout(button, list);
}
```

And that's how I set layout weight(same fot `Button` and `ListView`):

```
float weight = getColumnWeight(text); // returns 3f, 3f, 1f
button.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, weight));
```

After I add two columns it looks like this:

[image]

But when I add third one (with 1f layout width) everything goes weird like this (buttons look ok though):

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Full code of my main activity:

```
package ninja.majewski.myphonelibrary;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import ninja.majewski.myphonelibrary.data.BookList;

public class ListActivity extends Activity {

    private BookList bookList;

    private int numberOfLists = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

        bookList = new BookList();

        Button addFragmentButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addFragmentButton);
        addFragmentButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch(numberOfLists) {
                    case 0:
                        addButtonAndList("Title");
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        addButtonAndList("Author");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        addButtonAndList("No.");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        addButtonAndList("Date");
                        break;
                }

                numberOfLists++;
            }
        });
    }

    private void addButtonAndList(String columnName) {
        // returns a button with setted name and layout params
        Button button = getButton(columnName);
        // returns a list with setted name and layout params
        ListView list = getNewListView(columnName);
        // simply adds views to two of my layouts
        addToLayout(button, list);
    }

    private Button getButton(String text) {
        Button button = new Button(ListActivity.this);
        button.setText(text);
        float weight = getColumnWeight(text); // returns 3f, 3f, 1f
        button.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, weight));

        return button;
    }

    private float getColumnWeight(String text) {
        float value = 0;

        switch(text) {
            case "Title":
                value = 3f;
                break;
            case "Author":
                value = 3f;
                break;
            case "No.":
                value = 1f;
                break;
            case "Date":
                value = 2f;
                break;
        }

        return value;
    }

    private ListView getNewListView(String columnName) {
        ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();

        switch(columnName) {
        case "Title":
            values = bookList.getNamesList();
            break;
        case "Author":
            values = bookList.getAuthorsList();
            break;
        case "No.":
            values = bookList.getPagesList();
            break;
        case "Date":
            values = bookList.getDatesList();
            break;
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);

        ListView list = new ListView(this);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        float weight = getColumnWeight(columnName);
        System.out.println(weight);
        list.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, weight));

        return list;

    }

    private void addToLayout(Button button, ListView list) {
        LinearLayout layout1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.fragmentsHolder);
        layout1.addView(button);

        LinearLayout layout2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.listsHolder);
        layout2.addView(list);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using weights you should set the layout width to 0dp. Right now you're having each ListView decide it's own width with WRAP_CONTENT, then the LinearLayout is using the weights to decide how to shrink each view to fit them all.

```
new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, weight)
```